# Performance optimization of order by Random in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-order-by, query-optimization, dbt

There is a multi CTE query in DBT and one of the CTE contains order by `random()` in the query.

Does it has any impact on the query processing time or can it be removed to optimize the query?

Comment: order by random() is rarely efficient on ANY RDBMS

Comment: I can guess that its used to pick any random matching row. It can be removed and use `limit 1`  to extract random row. But you need to identify why they used a random row and remove/replace that logic.

Comment: If the `order by` is redundant, you could use Snowflake's `Query Profile` to test that.

Comment: As shown in the previous comment - we could give you better advice if you told us the goal of the query. Maybe `order by random` is important, maybe its not. But we can't tell with the information provided.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Snowflake's `TABLESAMPLE ROW (x ROWS)` table clause to return a sample of `x` rows from the table using Bernoulli sampling.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason to see an `order by random()` is to address data skew by forcing a redistribution of data at a particular point in the execution plan. It's probably there because of a recommendation from someone at Snowflake, perhaps Support. You can try removing it and test without it. If removing it makes the query run slower, it means that the `order by random()` is effectively redistributing skewed data and should be kept.